# How to turn off mootools in joomla 1.5 in backend

Tags: joomla

I am using jquery, but it conflicts with mootools. How do I turn off mootools in administrator of joomla 1.5?

Comment: if you turn off mootools in jooml backend lot of basic feature may stop working.
so you better try using jQuery in no conflict mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can not run the Joomla admin without the Mootools library, but you can run both without any conflict. You just have to use the following code when you use jQuery

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // your doc ready code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this link shows how to do it: [Disable Mootools](http://www.infyways.com/joomla-mootools/)

You might have to tweak a little for disabling it in backend only. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I am using following to completely remove Mootools and standard behaviors from Joomla 2.5. Just add following to your template's index.php

```
$headerstuff = $this->getHeadData();
foreach ($headerstuff['scripts'] as $k=>$item) {
 if (stristr($k, 'mootools-core.js'))
 unset($headerstuff['scripts'][$k]);
 if (stristr($k, 'mootools-more.js'))
 unset($headerstuff['scripts'][$k]);
 if (stristr($k, 'caption.js'))
 unset($headerstuff['scripts'][$k]);
 if (stristr($k, 'validate.js'))
 unset($headerstuff['scripts'][$k]);
}
$this->setHeadData($headerstuff);

if (isset($this->_script['text/javascript'])) {
 $this->_script['text/javascript'] = preg_replace('%window\.addEvent\(\'load\',\s*function\(\)\s*{\s*new\s*JCaption\(\'img.caption\'\);\s*}\);\s*%', '', $this->_script['text/javascript']);
 if (empty($this->_script['text/javascript']))
 unset($this->_script['text/javascript']);

 $this->_script['text/javascript'] = preg_replace( '/window\.addEvent[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\{\}\s*=\.\';:,\[\]\$]+/mi', '',  $this->_script['text/javascript']);
 if (empty($this->_script['text/javascript']))
 unset($this->_script['text/javascript']);
}
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', false);
$doc->addScript('...', false);
...
```